# retrieving a value from a plsql select procedure

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, plsql

From a table containing rfid strings (random varchar strings) I have to select a free rfid string that is not yet in used in another table, for that i use the following sql statement:

```
select *  from (
 select rfid 
 from rfid_col 
 where rfid not in (select rfid from person)
 )where rownum<=1;
```

the sql on itself works fine but then I needed to put it in a stored procedure

```
create or replace 
procedure getFreeRfid(rfidout out varchar2) is
begin
select * into rfidout 
from (select rfid from rfid_col where rfid not in (select rfid from person)
)where rownum<=1;
end getFreeRfid;
```

this code works fine in oracle sql developer

to retrieve this in C# using the oracle data I use the following code

```
 OracleCommand rfidcommand = db.connection.CreateCommand();
 rfidcommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 rfidcommand.CommandText = "getFreeRfid";
 rfidcommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("rfidout", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
 rfidcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
 string rfid = rfidcommand.Parameters["rfidout"].Value.ToString();
```

however somehow this throws:

```
A first chance exception of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in Oracle.DataAccess.dll
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "TIM.GETFREERFID", line 3
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

I have been struggling with this problem for quite some time now and this is my last solution

Comment: What is the type of `rfid`?

Comment: according to sql developer varchar2(10byte)

Comment: may we see both tables definitions?

Comment: I'm not even inserting it into the second table yet first I have to retrieve it into my program

Comment: CREATE TABLE RFID_col
(RFID varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);

Comment: "this code works fine in oracle sql developer", Does it mean you tested it calling the procedure?

Comment: yes I tested the procedure in sql studio and it worked like a charm returning the first free rfid string as intended

Comment: Have you tried using a normal function instead of a procedure with an output parameter?

Comment: I'm looking into that right now

Comment: This might be a longshot, but I have seen where other oracle drivers (ODBC) screw up the data type when returned from a view or function.  Try changing "select * from" to add a "cast" function to the explicit data type.

Comment: I have tried to cast it to a varchar2 but still got the same error. Thanks all for your help.I give up, I'll make a view for it and call that from C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to set size for strings when dealing with output parameters. The size sets automatically on Input parameters because it is known. I don't know if this will fix your issue but you will not get value if size not set on the output, not a full value anyway - you may get 1 character. And make sure that type in Db is indeed Varchar2

Please, try this code:

```
string connStr = ".........";
string result = null;
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand("getFreeRfid", conn))
    {
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        OracleParameter p = new OracleParameter("rfidout", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
        p.Size = 200;
        comm.Parameters.Add(p);
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        result = (string)comm.Parameters[0].Value;
    }
}
```

Good luck!
PS: `using` will help you close and dispose of command and connection.

Comment: I know this is not really allowed but sir YOU ARE AWESOME setting a size fixed the error

Comment: Enjoy the fix and Happy New Year :o)